# Controlling the space between title and first entry in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

Sorry if this is a newbie question, I am trying to reduce the number between the "BIBLIOGRAPHY" title and the first entery. I am using a custom bst my institution provided. The following are the relevant snipits:

```
FUNCTION {begin.bib}
{ preamble$ empty$
    'skip$
    { preamble$ write$ newline$ }
  if$
  "\begin{thebibliography}{" number.label int.to.str$ * "}" *
  write$ newline$
  "\providecommand{\natexlab}[1]{#1}"
  write$ newline$
  "\providecommand{\url}[1]{#1}"
  write$ newline$
  "\providecommand{\urlprefix}{}"
  write$ newline$
  "\expandafter\ifx\csname urlstyle\endcsname\relax"
  write$ newline$
  "  \providecommand{\doi}[1]{doi:\discretionary{}{}{}#1}\else"
  write$ newline$
  "  \providecommand{\doi}{doi:\discretionary{}{}{}\begingroup \urlstyle{rm}\Url}\fi"
  write$ newline$
}
```

Other than that everything seems pretty normal to my untrained eye

```
EXECUTE {begin.bib}
EXECUTE {init.state.consts}
ITERATE {call.type$}
FUNCTION {end.bib}
{ newline$
  "\end{thebibliography}" write$ newline$
}
EXECUTE {end.bib}
```

I deleted each an every `write$ newline$` thinking that at least one would give the desired result but to no avail, any ideas?

My document class is "\documentclass[]{my-thesis}". The cls has only one part that is relevant to the bibliography

```
% make the bibliography page
% new version modelled after memoir code for appendix page
% removed extraneous \vfils
\newcommand\mmm@bibpage{%
  \let\bibtocname\bibname % moved inside this page to beat apacite
  \let\bibpagename\bibname
  \cftinserthook{toc}{BIB}
  \settocdepth{subsubsection} % changed v2.7 to allow for chapter bibs
  \@setuppart
  \mmm@preaddbibpagetotochook
  \mmm@addbibheadtotoc
  \mmm@postaddbibpagetotochook
  \partmark{\bibpagename}%
  \mmm@bibpageinfo{\bibpagename}%
  {\centering
   \interlinepenalty \@M
   \normalfont
   \printparttitle{\bibpagename}\par}%
  \@endpart}
\newcommand\mmm@preaddbibpagetotochook{}
\newcommand\mmm@postaddbibpagetotochook{}
\newcommand{\mmm@bibpageinfo}[1]{}
\renewcommand{\prebibhook}{\vspace{\cftparskip}} % add extra space before entries to match ToC etc. 6/15/17
```

Thanks

Comment: Welcomet to TeX.SE. Please tell us which document class you employ. Hint: it's the LaTeX code in the document class file, and not the BibTeX code you posted above, that determines the default distance between the bibliography's header and the first formatted bibliographic item. The `write$ newline$` commands you've come across generate line breaks after each `\providecommand` instructions being written to the bbl file.

Comment: Hi, its a special cls provided by my institution "\documentclass[]{my-thesis}" I looked at the cls and it has one part of code that deal with the bib, will add to my original question

Comment: Is the class file available online?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use `\vfill\vfill` (as many as you need, or maybe just one `\vfill`)